# How can i append dictionary to my existing key "processed_data" in mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to append a dictionary to my already existing key "processed_data" where data is saved in the list of dictionaries. I tried several methods as shown in already asked questions but they did not work. This is my schema.

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5fe46a5b7468e3498124fcbe'), 'metadata': {'_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd86334f'), 'type': 'VIDEO', 'id': 'o6st4ces9Wg"},"qoeUrl":{"baseUrl":"https://s.youtube.com/api/stats/qoe?cl=348521801', 'user_id': 'fc3240b2d7ef9d33bbb04fd7203e35ea9da54ffb', 'name': 'City Ak47', 'thumbnail': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/o6st4ces9Wg/hqdefault.jpg', 'title': 'Alex Bhatti ki Video Viral Ho Gie | How To Become Tiktok Star | City AK47 - YouTube', 'publication_date': 'Sep 17, 2020', 'channel_id': 'UCuo6tBl2MfkWvMPyCqph2LA', 'channel_name': 'City Ak47', 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.390018', 'regions_allowed': 'AD,AE,AF,AG,AI,AL,AM,AO,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AU,AW,AX,AZ,BA,BB,BD,BE,BF,BG,BH,BI,BJ,BL,BM,BN,BO,BQ,BR,BS,BT,BV,BW,BY,BZ,CA,CC,CD,CF,CG,CH,CI,CK,CL,CM,CN,CO,CR,CU,CV,CW,CX,CY,CZ,DE,DJ,DK,DM,DO,DZ,EC,EE,EG,EH,ER,ES,ET,FI,FJ,FK,FM,FO,FR,GA,GB,GD,GE,GF,GG,GH,GI,GL,GM,GN,GP,GQ,GR,GS,GT,GU,GW,GY,HK,HM,HN,HR,HT,HU,ID,IE,IL,IM,IN,IO,IQ,IR,IS,IT,JE,JM,JO,JP,KE,KG,KH,KI,KM,KN,KP,KR,KW,KY,KZ,LA,LB,LC,LI,LK,LR,LS,LT,LU,LV,LY,MA,MC,MD,ME,MF,MG,MH,MK,ML,MM,MN,MO,MP,MQ,MR,MS,MT,MU,MV,MW,MX,MY,MZ,NA,NC,NE,NF,NG,NI,NL,NO,NP,NR,NU,NZ,OM,PA,PE,PF,PG,PH,PK,PL,PM,PN,PR,PS,PT,PW,PY,QA,RE,RO,RS,RU,RW,SA,SB,SC,SD,SE,SG,SH,SI,SJ,SK,SL,SM,SN,SO,SR,SS,ST,SV,SX,SY,SZ,TC,TD,TF,TG,TH,TJ,TK,TL,TM,TN,TO,TR,TT,TV,TW,TZ,UA,UG,UM,US,UY,UZ,VA,VC,VE,VG,VI,VN,VU,WF,WS,YE,YT,ZA,ZM,ZW', 'views': '663962', 'is_family_friendly': 'true', 'category': 'Entertainment', 'tags': ['AmirFilms', 'Alex Bhatti ki Video Viral Ho Gie | How To Become Tiktok Star | City AK47', 'Tiktok star', 'Tiktok', 'Alex tiktokr', 'Alex bhatti tiktok star', 'Alex bhatti', 'Ayesha bukhari', 'Viral video', 'New video', 'Leak vidro', 'Ayesha leak video', 'Alex bhatti leak video', 'News', 'Tiktik funny video'], 'language': 'en-US', 'width': '480', 'height': '360', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926'}, 'results': {'unique_word_freq': [{'text': 'hai', 'value': 6}, {'text': 'famous', 'value': 4}, {'text': 'allah', 'value': 3}, {'text': 'kar', 'value': 3}, {'text': 'gy', 'value': 3}, {'text': 'ye', 'value': 3}, {'text': 'yeh', 'value': 2}, {'text': 'ka', 'value': 2}, {'text': 'video', 'value': 2}, {'text': 'asee', 'value': 2}, {'text': 'nhi', 'value': 2}, {'text': 'ho', 'value': 2}, {'text': 'tum', 'value': 2}, {'text': 'jao', 'value': 2}, {'text': 'kitna', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'budsoor', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'gundgi', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'dher', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'khusra', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'tiktok', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'kunjuro', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'zanano', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'kaam', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'usko', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'hadyat', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'de', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'ameen', 'value': 1}, {'text': '', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'kahn', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'puri', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'kotta', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'ٹک', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'ٹاک', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'ایپ', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'پر', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'پاکستان', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'میں', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'مکمل', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'پابندی', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'لگنی', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'چاہیے', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'leaked', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'purpose', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'fame', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'views', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'mean', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'people', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'like', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'kinda', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'cheap', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'acts', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'inki', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'maa', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'bhano', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'sath', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'bhi', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'hoo', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'pak', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'ko', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'bohot', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'bari', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'sazaa', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'dee', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'duniyan', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'hee', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'dikhaee', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'pata', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'khha', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'jay', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'kiyamat', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'din', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'logo', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'hisab', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'lena', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'log', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'sidah', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'janat', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'chaly', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'baaz', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'ap', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'bakwas', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'band', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'kareen', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'larka', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'bharva', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'bs', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'pakar', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'gal', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'ma', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'dala', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'gaya', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'bahut', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'ghatiya', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'insan', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'tu', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'chakka', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'alex', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'bhatti', 'value': 1}], 'polarity_freq': [{'date': '2020-12-03', 'total': 4, 'positive': 3, 'negative': 1}, {'date': '2020-12-10', 'total': 9, 'positive': 8, 'negative': 1}, {'date': '2020-12-17', 'total': 2, 'positive': 2, 'negative': 0}, {'date': '2020-12-21', 'total': 1, 'positive': 1, 'negative': 0}, {'date': '2020-12-22', 'total': 2, 'positive': 1, 'negative': 1}], 'polarity_dist': [{'name': 'positive', 'value': '15'}, {'name': 'negative', 'value': '3'}], 'assoc': []}, 'processed_data': [{'index': 0, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863350'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCg7rf8yXy8wqVxlbnErgdyg', 'clean_text': 'kitna budsoor hai yeh gundgi ka dher khusra', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwniDMBIClPo0sPLX5RDOLPHTJhECMOub-fC0ZTVY6Q=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-22 08:23:17', 'id': 'UgxzkGuC2JpeaZD7El14AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '2 days ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'Kitna budsoor hai yeh gundgi ka dher khusra.', 'tokens': ['kitna', 'budsoor', 'hai', 'yeh', 'gundgi', 'ka', 'dher', 'khusra'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['kitna', 'budsoor', 'hai', 'yeh', 'gundgi', 'ka', 'dher', 'khusra'], 'tran_text': 'kitna budsoor hai yeh gundgi ka dher khusra .', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': 'f7961259b974ba9fae934410fca2e939d3493038', 'user_name': 'jimmi khan', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '1', 'date': '2020-12-22'}, {'index': 1, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863351'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCg7rf8yXy8wqVxlbnErgdyg', 'clean_text': 'tiktok kunjuro zanano ka kaam hai', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwniDMBIClPo0sPLX5RDOLPHTJhECMOub-fC0ZTVY6Q=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-22 08:23:17', 'id': 'UgwntMkhi7J2l2N3MZJ4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '2 days ago (edited)', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'Tiktok kunjuro r zanano ka kaam hai.', 'tokens': ['tiktok', 'kunjuro', 'zanano', 'ka', 'kaam', 'hai'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['tiktok', 'kunjuro', 'zanano', 'ka', 'kaam', 'hai'], 'tran_text': 'tiktok kunjuro r zanano ka kaam hai .', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': 'f7961259b974ba9fae934410fca2e939d3493038', 'user_name': 'jimmi khan', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-22'}, {'index': 2, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863352'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCMDNByou1B62upgmnv-UQMw', 'clean_text': 'allah usko hadyat de ameen ', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnik2uW0mzYoagKEYX1_kGY3HDhYd3Ni6UlOxSEHOA=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-21 08:23:17', 'id': 'UgxZrbzomoOLyGEGAjp4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '3 days ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'Allah usko hadyat de ameen ', 'tokens': ['allah', 'usko', 'hadyat', 'de', 'ameen', ''], 'tokens_no_swords': ['allah', 'usko', 'hadyat', 'de', 'ameen', ''], 'tran_text': 'allah usko hadyat de ameen ', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': 'da9fe12c7945488a70f56355f8c122d2f35231c5', 'user_name': 'neha Rajput', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-21'}, {'index': 3, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863353'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCkl4U918shu8CroBno8-aJg', 'clean_text': '', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwniom0S4ta4uSnNx7yD69NfR4TmOqXPpYxv6_Q=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-17 08:23:17', 'id': 'UgzAfvcluRdyX9yi-JJ4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '1 week ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': '420', 'tokens': [], 'tokens_no_swords': [], 'tran_text': '420', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': '04b4dd4534a4acf47ba876387d752eda8d3087f6', 'user_name': 'Shahid Khankarachi', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-17'}, {'index': 5, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863355'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCoL0h9EyBTNSvKIWIxl6WIg', 'clean_text': 'kahn hai yeh puri video', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnjNJAzxyS9mOk-R7TF5ICxa0_EQbtgcL3z2Yg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-17 08:23:17', 'id': 'Ugxx-JvihbK7P8Y8u5x4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '1 week ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'Kahn hai yeh puri video', 'tokens': ['kahn', 'hai', 'yeh', 'puri', 'video'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['kahn', 'hai', 'yeh', 'puri', 'video'], 'tran_text': 'kahn hai yeh puri video', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': '3bc410f7e5133b61e2f2cc790ce6ae2692397778', 'user_name': 'ALISHA ZOYA', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-17'}, {'index': 6, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863356'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCsd6TX3yWpNYK55hawyi8qw', 'clean_text': 'kotta', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnj19uWVIJ75wx27KLjDGDcsVcGtzVtp8SRQ0w=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-10 08:23:17', 'id': 'UgyhHfBJDWHtL73E71N4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '2 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'Kotta', 'tokens': ['kotta'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['kotta'], 'tran_text': 'kotta', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': 'e83b422e66c1bd722306aee6715c3846c32e506b', 'user_name': 'Shakeel Khan', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-10'}, {'index': 7, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863357'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCX6LjA5LbC7xMO19yyM7m0Q', 'clean_text': 'ٹک ٹاک ایپ پر پاکستان میں مکمل پابندی لگنی چاہیے', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwni4WpKnrXzHmw2VwT0z5aYnM0T5IhRN0DG3Pmsg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-10 08:23:17', 'id': 'UgwFILpwDAQKYA9ioMV4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'en', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '2 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'ٹک ٹاک ایپ پر پاکستان میں مکمل پابندی لگنی چاہیے', 'tokens': ['ٹک', 'ٹاک', 'ایپ', 'پر', 'پاکستان', 'میں', 'مکمل', 'پابندی', 'لگنی', 'چاہیے'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['ٹک', 'ٹاک', 'ایپ', 'پر', 'پاکستان', 'میں', 'مکمل', 'پابندی', 'لگنی', 'چاہیے'], 'tran_text': 'ٹک ٹاک ایپ پر پاکستان میں مکمل پابندی لگنی چاہیے', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': '9ca6083ff6234bd94fc218ef27d12c8b91c2fa33', 'user_name': 'Wahab Mirza', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-10'}, {'index': 8, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863358'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCKMvpfSppW24ixWCOmJDu_g', 'clean_text': 'he leaked this video on purpose to get fame and views i mean people like them do these kinda cheap acts to get famous', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwniL8sePcWPsqDg6AOaLsW4nf14XDW3132kC0Q=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-10 08:23:17', 'id': 'Ugz7IdhD6s8zCJ6vHNt4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'en', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '2 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'He leaked this video on purpose to get fame and views...I mean people like them do these kinda cheap acts to get famous.', 'tokens': ['he', 'leaked', 'this', 'video', 'on', 'purpose', 'to', 'get', 'fame', 'and', 'views', 'i', 'mean', 'people', 'like', 'them', 'do', 'these', 'kinda', 'cheap', 'acts', 'to', 'get', 'famous'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['leaked', 'video', 'purpose', 'fame', 'views', 'mean', 'people', 'like', 'kinda', 'cheap', 'acts', 'famous'], 'tran_text': 'he leaked this video on purpose to get fame and views ... i mean people like them do these kinda cheap acts to get famous .', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': '3f75585892685df3ae4b3d733d9795a719b2d528', 'user_name': 'Ana T', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-10'}, {'index': 9, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863359'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCSUGRfHKn5qCNN4TKG3MAkw', 'clean_text': '', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwng6eAHeRd7CcM8mmkCHCA8VI2tqmMNPb1q1MA=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-10 08:23:17', 'id': 'UgwMvbYR29V4ISyic_d4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'en', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '2 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': '03065455318', 'tokens': [], 'tokens_no_swords': [], 'tran_text': '03065455318', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': '23ac482ba9b36182915c502c13d4cd45b7f7bf1f', 'user_name': 'Ali Rizwan', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-10'}, {'index': 10, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd86335a'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UC-fWQ2vkmngdVliZDkRSiiQ', 'clean_text': 'inki maa bhano sath bhi asee hoo', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwngl0V2Zy_AUGUyIZpMbrBDxqL6pq5AcdF4hNg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-10 08:23:17', 'id': 'UgzEMbiRNk2ywQHlgxR4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '2 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'Inki maa bhano k sath bhi Asee hoo', 'tokens': ['inki', 'maa', 'bhano', 'sath', 'bhi', 'asee', 'hoo'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['inki', 'maa', 'bhano', 'sath', 'bhi', 'asee', 'hoo'], 'tran_text': 'inki maa bhano k sath bhi asee hoo', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': '2c7e490aa5d0ceca9340c92c3577fa75d3e5a8d3', 'user_name': 'M wali Yousuf', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-10'}, {'index': 11, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd86335b'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UC-fWQ2vkmngdVliZDkRSiiQ', 'clean_text': 'allah pak asee ko bohot bari sazaa dee or duniyan me hee dikhaee', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwngl0V2Zy_AUGUyIZpMbrBDxqL6pq5AcdF4hNg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-10 08:23:17', 'id': 'Ugyo9YlNa7zuVsSQlZh4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '2 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'Allah Pak Asee ko Bohot bari Sazaa Dee Or Duniyan me hee dikhaee', 'tokens': ['allah', 'pak', 'asee', 'ko', 'bohot', 'bari', 'sazaa', 'dee', 'or', 'duniyan', 'me', 'hee', 'dikhaee'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['allah', 'pak', 'asee', 'ko', 'bohot', 'bari', 'sazaa', 'dee', 'duniyan', 'hee', 'dikhaee'], 'tran_text': 'allah pak asee ko bohot bari sazaa dee or duniyan me hee dikhaee', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': '2c7e490aa5d0ceca9340c92c3577fa75d3e5a8d3', 'user_name': 'M wali Yousuf', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-10'}, {'index': 12, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd86335c'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCphcNEEoxrp08DARCX7dSNQ', 'clean_text': 'pata nhi famous ho kar khha jay gy kiyamat din allah famous logo hisab lena hai ye nhi tum log famous ho gy or sidah janat chaly jao gy baaz a jao', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnibNbjcM0UMLW2aTnOD3jfJXlaq2Iq5_hMg3Q-O=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-10 08:23:17', 'id': 'UgzfXCaZHDMSCKPqlKB4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': '1', 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '2 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'Pata nhi famous ho Kar khha jay gy. Kiyamat k din Allah n famous logo c b hisab lena hai ye nhi k tum log famous ho gy or sidah janat m chaly jao gy. Baaz a jao', 'tokens': ['pata', 'nhi', 'famous', 'ho', 'kar', 'khha', 'jay', 'gy', 'kiyamat', 'din', 'allah', 'famous', 'logo', 'hisab', 'lena', 'hai', 'ye', 'nhi', 'tum', 'log', 'famous', 'ho', 'gy', 'or', 'sidah', 'janat', 'chaly', 'jao', 'gy', 'baaz', 'a', 'jao'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['pata', 'nhi', 'famous', 'ho', 'kar', 'khha', 'jay', 'gy', 'kiyamat', 'din', 'allah', 'famous', 'logo', 'hisab', 'lena', 'hai', 'ye', 'nhi', 'tum', 'log', 'famous', 'ho', 'gy', 'sidah', 'janat', 'chaly', 'jao', 'gy', 'baaz', 'jao'], 'tran_text': 'pata nhi famous ho kar khha jay gy . kiyamat k din allah n famous logo c b hisab lena hai ye nhi k tum log famous ho gy or sidah janat m chaly jao gy . baaz a jao', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': 'da5c845fbd0a39db29a99a9d620bd8c266956065', 'user_name': 'Rida Khan', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '1', 'date': '2020-12-10'}, {'index': 13, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd86335d'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCnVVsV2fd3P0lS9QClU5DCA', 'clean_text': 'ap bakwas band kareen', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwniJxcGaZeKzmvDSUGeX5vFZo3m_ZXQ_yC7-Kw=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-10 08:23:17', 'id': 'UgwzEHvn_WWTbPOzl7x4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '2 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'Ap bakwas band kareen', 'tokens': ['ap', 'bakwas', 'band', 'kareen'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['ap', 'bakwas', 'band', 'kareen'], 'tran_text': 'ap bakwas band kareen', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': 'e51ff2c592a9ad2fe8f6f373c6a2dab117f2c2e9', 'user_name': 'ahmad muaaz', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-10'}, {'index': 14, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd86335e'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCtbUvUvL0qrREfEzUvJUQKQ', 'clean_text': 'ye larka bharva', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnjKBfmUKuMzFCtwM-KuKAfq_5y0RA7iez5w9Q=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-10 08:23:17', 'id': 'UgzvW63udc6CEwnsb_J4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '2 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'ye larka bharva', 'tokens': ['ye', 'larka', 'bharva'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['ye', 'larka', 'bharva'], 'tran_text': 'ye larka bharva', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': '7d7c7165c38c05a96c335421faf6ca3eb9eb1722', 'user_name': 'Rana Waqas', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-10'}, {'index': 15, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd86335f'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCieduNjSrF2DPawdZh_HesQ', 'clean_text': 'bs kar do tum', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwniOEn-mQTkzQu5ybCc6gjFqSlK8eQF-4RsB6w=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-03 08:23:17', 'id': 'Ugx9gyNwYeVV5DDKsJV4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '3 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'bs kar do tum', 'tokens': ['bs', 'kar', 'do', 'tum'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['bs', 'kar', 'tum'], 'tran_text': 'bs kar do tum', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': '7339de48d380c9efe854dc9b6660a8fe22c28448', 'user_name': 'sami ali ali', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-03'}, {'index': 16, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863360'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCaPZsZzHcOMiDgZ3rkALMFg', 'clean_text': 'is pakar kar gal ma dala gaya', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnhv4vXDX16Pi0veGMZVUtqiYiYq_XOUp2yTvQ=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-03 08:23:17', 'id': 'UgzC4DaDahEFvjUsJiN4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '3 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'Is pakar kar gal ma dala gaya', 'tokens': ['is', 'pakar', 'kar', 'gal', 'ma', 'dala', 'gaya'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['pakar', 'kar', 'gal', 'ma', 'dala', 'gaya'], 'tran_text': 'is pakar kar gal ma dala gaya', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': 'ae974ed633daab66164b5dcee9340e2ed0b1c455', 'user_name': 'munir gill', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '1', 'date': '2020-12-03'}, {'index': 17, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863361'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCqGRwUGDEBY98v0PcA9BpUQ', 'clean_text': 'bahut ghatiya insan hai', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnhMts6KGq4VtnvbDuVVatNlFduO6jmHbIRX6A=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-03 08:23:17', 'id': 'UgyyCAdkym_IDptSbNZ4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '3 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'Bahut ghatiya insan hai', 'tokens': ['bahut', 'ghatiya', 'insan', 'hai'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['bahut', 'ghatiya', 'insan', 'hai'], 'tran_text': 'bahut ghatiya insan hai', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': '331593ec91edb449953d775229e7a91727415976', 'user_name': 'Asif Bhatti', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-03'}, {'index': 18, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863362'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCBZ0mLPPioFWW1i-kvmZBnA', 'clean_text': 'ye tu chakka hai alex bhatti', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnggrksT4HvfysI9VkzPzsKIXkcJsPfmWvvNyg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-03 08:23:17', 'id': 'Ugwh57O9lzDJgzCvKJV4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '3 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'Ye tu chakka hai alex bhatti', 'tokens': ['ye', 'tu', 'chakka', 'hai', 'alex', 'bhatti'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['ye', 'tu', 'chakka', 'hai', 'alex', 'bhatti'], 'tran_text': 'ye tu chakka hai alex bhatti', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': 'ee99e20e5128b5fc14c1972d55625585cf4d0237', 'user_name': 'Khizar Rao', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-03'}]}
```

I want to append the following dictionary against the "processed_data" key.

```
{'index': 19, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863362'), 'channel_id': '/channel/UCBZ0mLPPioFWW1i-kvmZBnA', 'clean_text': 'ye tu chakka hai alex bhatti', 'comment_user_image': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnggrksT4HvfysI9VkzPzsKIXkcJsPfmWvvNyg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'datetime': '2020-12-03 08:23:17', 'id': 'Ugwh57O9lzDJgzCvKJV4AaABAg', 'job_id': '539f61c4183c46448a75cfb65dc40926', 'lang': 'ro-ur', 'likes': 0, 'orig_lang': 'unknown', 'published_time_display': '3 weeks ago', 'replies': None, 'reply_to': None, 'scrape_date': '2020-12-24 08:23:17.955821', 'text': 'Ye tu chakka hai alex bhatti', 'tokens': ['ye', 'tu', 'chakka', 'hai', 'alex', 'bhatti'], 'tokens_no_swords': ['ye', 'tu', 'chakka', 'hai', 'alex', 'bhatti'], 'tran_text': 'ye tu chakka hai alex bhatti', 'type': 'COMMENT', 'user_id': 'ee99e20e5128b5fc14c1972d55625585cf4d0237', 'user_name': 'Khizar Rao', 'video_id': 'o6st4ces9Wg', 'is_hate': '0', 'date': '2020-12-03'}
```

Thanks!

Comment: finally solved by collection.update({"_id": _id}, {"$push": {data: {'$each': chunk}}})

Answer (score 0):

Use `update_one()` with [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import  ObjectId

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.mycollection.insert_one({'_id': ObjectId('5fe46a5b7468e3498124fcbe'),
                            'processed_data': []})

update = {'index': 19, '_id': ObjectId('5fe4500c7b2c03decd863362'), 'channel_id': 'etc.'}

db.mycollection.update_one({'_id': ObjectId('5fe46a5b7468e3498124fcbe')}, {'$push': {'processed_data': update}})
```

Comment: I tried that and it overwrites my existing data

Comment: "That" won't overwrite your data, so you're doing something wrong. Post your code.